# What are the complete set of instruments and number of players in the Rocky and Bullwinkle Theme

Tags: soundtrack, identify-this-instrument

In the theme for the cartoon Rocky and Bullwinkle written by George Steiner and Frank Comstock, what are the instruments used and how many distinct players are there?

My guess is:
1 flute/piccolo
1 trumpet (or 2?)
1 clarinet (or doubled with bassoon?)
1 bassoon (player doubles on clarinet?)
1 Tuba
1 Trombone
1 xylophone and other percussion (at the end I hear sandpaper)

I am guessing that some of the players are doubling other instruments. But for the players that double which instruments are they doubling?

My guess is that there really are only 7 people total.

Are the two trumpets playing parallel tritones in the beginning?  Or maybe parallel 4th's out of tune? Or maybe parallel tritones out of tune so they sound like parallel fourths?

One interesting thing about the opening is that the two trumpets do not sound as though they are sitting together.